# Entity Framework: Many-to-Many relations with abstract classes, modify without querying database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

With Entity Framework, if I have the following model:

```cs
class Asset {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AssetGroup> Groups { get; set; }
}

class AssetGroup {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
}
```

Adding an existing asset to a given group without having to query the database to load the asset in question is relatively straightforward:

```cs
using(var context = new MyContext()) {
    AssetGroup assetGroup = context.AssetGroups.Find(groupId);

    // Create a fake Asset to avoid a db query
    Asset temp = context.Assets.Create();
    temp.Id = assetId;
    context.Assets.Attach(temp);

    assetGroup.Assets.Add(temp);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, I now have the problem that I have extended the model so that there are multiple Asset types, implemented as an inheritance hierarchy. In the process, the Asset class has been made abstract, since an asset with no specific type makes no sense:

```cs
abstract class Asset {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AssetGroup> Groups { get; set; }
}

class SpecificAsset1 : Asset {
    public string OneProperty { get; set; }
}

class SpecificAsset2 : Asset {
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that now the `Create()` call throws an `InvalidOperationException` because "Instances of abstract classes cannot be created", which of course makes sense.

So, the question is, how can I update the many-to-many relation without having to go fetch the Asset from the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the generic [`Create<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696685%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method of `DbSet<T>` to create a derived entity object.

```
var temp1 = context.Assets.Create<SpecificAsset1>();
```

and continue from here using `temp1` as a *stub entity* the way you already did.

Comment: Interesting, it seems like EF won't barf because of type mismatch (ie, when assetId refers to a SpecificAsset2). Good to know.

Comment: However, in my actual code where I hit this problem is in a generic method I created, where I don't necessarily know which type I can substitute (without using reflection, at least). So a solution that doesn't involve knowing the type hierarchy would be nice.

Comment: Can you use the type as parameter (as in `typeof(SpecificAsset1)`)?

Comment: I could, but then I would have to dynamically invoke the Create<T> method... Doable, but not quite elegant

Comment: Marking as accepted since there appears to not be a better solution.
Thanks!