# Entity Framework - many to many relationship - add reference with id

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, ef-code-first, code-first

I use entity framework and I have many to many relationship between 2  objects.

Lets say class "question" and class "tag", when I create a new question with many tags, I have list of selected tags in viewmodel. I need to create the question so these tags are added to question but I do not want to reload all the tags.

I mean :

```
foreach(var id in tagUIds)
 {Tag tag = gettag(id);
 question.tags.add(tag); }
```

is not very efficient, is there a way to avoid loading the tag and adding the reference just by id of tag?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework: Many-to-Many relations with abstract classes, modify without querying database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901350/entity-framework-many-to-many-relations-with-abstract-classes-modify-without-q)

Answer (score 0):

You can create intermediate entity TagToQuestionLink, map it to many-to-many table and use Collection of this entity in question instead of collection of Tags:

```
public class TagToQuestionLink
{    
    TagId{get;set;}
    QuestionId{get;set;}
}
```

Then you can use:

```
foreach(var id in tagUIds)
{
   var tagLink = new TagToQuestionLink{QuestionId = question.Id, TagId = id};
   question.tags.add(tagLink); 
}
```

**Do not forget, that in this solution question.tags should be `ICollection<TagToQuestionLink>`**.